# Error Messages not showing during wiki config

Tags: 20.04, php, mediawiki

I am trying to launch mediawiki 1.18.6 on an ubuntu EC2 instance (so to then migrate another wiki from an old server onto it) to do this I've installed php5.6. However when going onto the mw-config page to configure the wiki, the error messages in error boxes don't seem to appear.
[image: error box with no message showing]

Going into the apache2 error logs I found the following:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 835 

preg_replace(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 839  

preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: group name must start with a non-digit at offset 4 in /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/MagicWord.php on line 834
```

I cannot upgrade the mediawiki or php version as the migration won't work, any ideas on what is causing this error or possible fixes?

Comment: While this comment is far too late to be of use, that specific version of MediaWiki was released in November of 2012. If you need to use very specific versions of PHP to perform the migration, the only realistic way to do this would be via Docker containers that allow for testing of the old PHP code. Either that, or you'll need to roll up your sleeves and begin making changes to the MediaWiki source to correct the deprecated function calls. It will not be a simple process.